# d3 on.click function argument, version 5 vs 6

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When upgrading from d3 5 to 6, I noticed that the function argument to the `clicked` function in

```js
.on("click", clicked)
```

changes to a `MouseEvent`. How to get the object that was previously passed. (Not sure what it is exactly.)

Comment: It will be the second argument.